# LNK2019: Unresolved External with Collidable Game Engine system

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

So I am currently working on a basic game engine with a collision system. For that system I have a CollidableGroup template class which objects register themselves too. However, I am not super experienced with templates and am running into an unresolved external error.

The class is a Singleton and the problem is comming from my GetInstance() method which is being called in the register/deregister.

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef CollidableGroup_
#define CollidableGroup_

#include "ContainerAlias.h"
//#include "Collidable.h"

template<class CollidableType>
class CollidableGroup {
public:

    static const KL::CollidableList& GetCollideableCollection() {
        GetInstance().PrivateGetColliableCollection();
    };

    static void Register(CollidableType& collidable_) {
        GetInstance().PrivateRegister(collidable_);
    };
    static void Deregister(CollidableType& collidable_) {
        //GetInstance().PrivateDeregister(collidable_)
    };

private:

    CollidableGroup();
    CollidableGroup<CollidableType>(const CollidableGroup<CollidableType>&) = delete;
    CollidableGroup<CollidableType>& operator=(const CollidableGroup<CollidableType>&) = delete;
    ~CollidableGroup() {
        instance = nullptr;
    };

    static CollidableGroup<CollidableType>* instance;
    static CollidableGroup<CollidableType>& GetInstance() {
        if(!instance)
        {
            instance = new CollidableGroup<CollidableType>;
        }
        return *instance;
    }

    void Delete() {};

    KL::CollidableList mCollidableCollection;

    void PrivateDeregister(CollidableType&) {};
    void PrivateRegister(CollidableType& collideable_) {
        mCollidableCollection.insert(mCollidableCollection.end(), &collideable_);
    };

    const KL::CollidableList& PrivateGetColliableCollection() {
        return mCollideablCollection;
    };



};

template <typename CollidableType>
CollidableGroup<CollidableType>* CollidableGroup<CollidableType>::instance = nullptr;

//template<class CollidableType>
//inline void CollidableGroup<CollidableType>::Register(CollidableType & /*collidable_*/) {
//  GetInstance();// .PrivateRegister(collidable_);
//};

#endif //!CollidableGroup_
```

ERROR:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: KatanaEngine, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Tank.cpp
1>Tank.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __thiscall CollidableGroup<class Tank>::CollidableGroup<class Tank>(void)" (??0?$CollidableGroup@VTank@@@@AAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: static class CollidableGroup<class Tank> & __cdecl CollidableGroup<class Tank>::GetInstance(void)" (?GetInstance@?$CollidableGroup@VTank@@@@CAAAV1@XZ)
1>C:\Users\David_Desktop\Perforce\dklimavi_DESKTOP\berthiaume2018winter_gam374\student\dklimavi\Sprint_6\katanaenginerep\KatanaEngine\Debug\KatanaEngine_Debug.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "KatanaEngine.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: Screen Shot of the Error]

Comment: Is the full error message secret?

Comment: Sorry!! I meant to do that - just posted the error message :)

Comment: It seems you have not implemented your constructor `CollidableGroup()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mostly what @drescherjm said, you declared a constructor, but the implementation isn't in your template definition, in the .h

```
CollidableGroup();
```

You should at least do something like this:

```
CollidableGroup() = default;
```

or

```
CollidableGroup() {};
```

if you implemented it in the .cpp, it won't work. You need to write the implementation in the h file when you work with template.

Comment: That was it! wow, i feel very stupid haha... thank you so much guys - I have been stuck on this for longer than I am willing to admit.